# How do you pass an updated state to a method - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

I'm working on this app where I'm using a Bluetooth library (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and I need to use base64 to pass a String from user input to a Bluetooth module. I'm quite new to React Native so here was my approach to accomplishing this task:

1. In the constructor I made a new state of input string

```js
constructor() {
        super()
        this.manager = new BleManager()
        this.setState = {inputString: ''};
    }
```

2. Then I added a way to update the inputString state when entering a string:

```html
<TextInput 
       style ={styles.input}
       placeholder = 'e.g. Hello'
       placeholderTextColor = 'white'
       onChangeText = {inputString => this.setState({inputString})}/>
```

3. Next I added a function to convert the user inputted string into base64 so that I can use it for a Bluetooth method to write to the module:

```js
encode = () =>{
        var encodedName = base64.encode(this.state.inputString);
        alert(encodedName);
    }
```

4. Finally I want to use that new updated variable (encodedName) in a method from the Bluetooth library. The method is as follows -

device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(

serviceUUID: UUID,

characteristicUUID: UUID,

valueBase64: Base64)

Here is my version of that code:

```js
device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('12ab', '34cd', 'base64')
     .then((characteristic) => {
      console.log(characteristic.value);
      return })
```

- This is where my issue is. Can I just call the function instead of 'base64', or is there some other way to call the updated variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should pass the encoded string as third parameter to the write function instead:

```
const base64Data = base64.encode(this.state.inputString);
device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('12ab', '34cd', base64Data);
```

Comment: Is it possible that I haven't encoded the string properly? I'm getting an error saying that "TypeError: input.charCodeAt is not a function. (In 'input.charCodeAt(i++)', 'input.charCodeAt' is undefined)" in the base64 class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hm. When you console.log `this.state.inputString` right before encoding it, does it have the correct value? Are you using the encode function from `react-native-base64` or is it another library?